# App android crash when opening camera on samsung galaxy s4 mini

Tags: android, camera, crash, photo

i just want to ask you something that i can't find a solution.

I have a samsung galaxy s4 mini and i'm trying to do something with the camera, and sometimes it crashes, but it doesn't give me any error.

I got this code:

```
 private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
 if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     // Create the File where the photo should go
     File photoFile = null;
     try {
         photoFile = createImageFile();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     // Continue only if the File was successfully created
     if (photoFile != null) {
         takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                 Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

         startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
     }
 }
}

 private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
 // Create an image file name
 String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new    Date());
 String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
 String directory = "appname" + File.separator + "images";
 String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + directory;
 File storageDir = new File(path);
 storageDir.mkdirs();

 File image = File.createTempFile(
     imageFileName, /* prefix */
     ".jpg", /* suffix */
     storageDir /* directory */
 );

 // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
 mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
 return image;
 }


@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
 if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && mCurrentPhotoPath != null) { 

  File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
  BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),
                btmapOptions);

  Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,(int)(bm.getWidth()*0.6), (int)(bm.getHeight()*0.6), true);

  mUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        sendPhoto(Constants.encodeTobase64(resizedBitmap));
 } else {
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
 Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
   });
  }
 }
```

Sometimes, when the application is in the method createImageFile(), the var mCurrentPhotoPath always have value, but when the app is in the method onActivityResult(), sometimes this value is NULL and is when this fails. The application just get closed and i don't have any type of error. It's a little strange, because sometimes it works (i did like 15 consecutive and the 16 failed..) .

The strangest thing is that when I try this app in another phone, it works so..there is any solution?

Thank you all and sorry for being too annoying on this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you current activity which is calling camera intent. are killed by android os because of lack of resources. that's why when return from camera app . your current activity restarted. if you want to check please put log in oncreate method. to solve this issue you have to store mCurrentPhotoPath store in onSaveInstanceState Method and Retrive it on onCreate Method for more info please refer [Google devloper site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) .

Comment: This would imply that the activity has been destroyed then? Lollipop is supposed to be less on the system, so why is this happening now?

Comment: Yes @mcd is right. due to lake of resources android will destroy your activity and gives the memory to camera intent.

Comment: Thanks, this works right, I've found a way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with Samsung and Lollipop. It is blowing away the activity instead of returning to it from the camera.

This should fix your problem:

```
File file = new File(createImageFile());
```

Also remember to call createImageFile() before opening camera so you will have the file path to save the picture to.

Comment: i don't think so this is not a bug i never face it . i think activity is killed because of camera app opens and it require resources .he had to use mCurrentPhotoPath in to onsaveinstancestate and retrive it on oncreate().

Comment: ran into a huge problem with an app I support in this exact same issue. Only happens on Samsung running Lollipop.